# Verifying the law around hosting an online crypto casino in the US

Tags: united-states, european-union, gambling, cryptocurrency

Can a site operator, resident in the USA in a state that doesn't allow online gambling, legally run an online casino site, provided that the site  Terms And Services document states:

> it is prohibited to use the site/service in any state, province, or country that does not allow online gambling.

1. What legal problems would there be if such a site was hosted in the US?
2. Would the legal position be different if the site was hosted in EU, where it is legal to gamble online?
3. Does the residence of the site operator or owner matter?

Comment: Gambling laws vary from State to State within the US, and even within different jurisdictions within some states. The laws are also different for Native American tribes, and may be limited differently for each tribe, depending on multiple factors. Thus, this question is **way too broad** to answer in this format. However, the brief answer is that it would be illegal, or at least unlawful, to run the online casino in many, if not most, jurisdictions. The residence of the site owner, may, or may not matter, where they do business, including business travel, almost certainly matters.

Comment: I agree with Makyen, way too broad. Personally, I think removing questions 1 & 2 would be sufficient to narrow the scope.